# App Gateway path based routing not working with ILB ASE

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-virtual-network, azure-app-service-envrmnt

We have an ILB ASE with `2` Web Apps running in it :

```
app1.mydomain.local
app2.mydomain.local
```

We have an Application Gateway in front of this to make the apps securely accessible from the Internet.  The Application Gateway has the following configurations:

Backend pool: `myapp-beap` - points to the IP of the ILB

Health Probe 1: `app1-probe` - Host = `app1.mydomain.local`

Health Probe 2: `app2-probe` - Host = `app2.mydomain.local`

HTTP Setting 1: `app1-httpSetting` - Custom Probe: `app1-probe` Host name: `app1.mydomain.local`

HTTP Setting 2: `app2-httpSetting` - Custom Probe: `app2-probe` Host name: `app2.mydomain.local`

Listener: `myapp-listener` Frontend port: 80

Path-based rule: `myapp-rule`

- Listener: `myapp-listener`
- Default backend pool: `myapp-beap`
- Default HTTP settings: `app1-httpSetting`
- Additional route: NAME: `API` PATHS: `/api/*` BACKEND POOL: `myapp-beap` HTTP SETTING: `app2-httpSetting`

The `app1.mydomain.local` app is the UI for our application and it makes calls to the `app2.mydomain.local` app.  The goal is to be able to access the UI by going to `app1.mydomain.com` and then map `app1.mydomain.com/api/` to `app2.mydomain.local` so that we can get a single certificate for the entire solution.

With the configuration detailed above, we can easily get to `app1.mydomain.com` but when we try to go to `app1.mydomain.com/api/` it gives us :

> The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

The vast majority of information we have found on the Internet related to path-based routing relates to routing to multiple different VMs.  There is almost nothing for doing this with App Services and even less when it is inside of an ILB ASE.

Comment: I suggest you to follow the link below and make sure you run test on AG. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-create-url-route-portal

Comment: @ZahidFaroq we have seen that article and it really does not help with our scenario because of the App Service Environment.

Comment: Do you need to inspect and audit all outbound traffic in Azure ASE?

Answer (score 0):

I was dealing with this as well. The answer to your question is that you will need to create identical mapping from the Application Gateway to the ILB ASE.

app1.mydomain.com/api/ to app2.mydomain.local/api/

You are seeing the that message because app2.mydomain.local/api/ currently doesn't exist. I know, I thought initially that it would mapped to the root of the ILB ASE environment as well.

I hope this help,
Hai

We are all looking for answers, some of us are more lucky than others. -Unknown

Comment: Also, I didn't see it mentioned on your original post but you will have to make these changes to the Application Gateway as well to have the host header be changed to the one that will be needed to target the application within the ILB ASE.

"Both the switch -PickHostNamefromBackendHttpSettingson the Probe configuration and -PickHostNameFromBackendAddress on the back-end http settings must be provided in order for web apps to work."

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/create-web-app